# How to Exclude Fields From Form Validation but Save the Cleaned Data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Edit: I'm not asking how to avoid the model fields being validated; I understand why it's required. I'm asking how I could skip over only the checks I wrote when I override the form's clean() method. I want the cleaned_data without it going through the other validation I wrote.

Let's say I have a ModelForm with the options to "save" and "Archive" (i.e. save for later) which only appear in the post_data if they are clicked. If the user clicks "save", the form would go through all the validation (including some custom logic in form.clean()) like normal. If the user clicks "archive" none of the custom validation in the form.clean() should run but the data should be saved.

In forms.py, I tried defining my form.clean() method as something like this:

```
def clean(self, full_clean=True):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    if full_clean:
        # All my validation
        ...
        ...
    return cleaned_data
```

Then in my views.py:

```
...
...
if request.method == "POST":
    post_data = request.POST
    if post_data.get('save') != None: # Do all validation
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cleaned_form = form.cleaned_data
            ...
            ...
        else: # If not valid
            # Do something with the errors
            ...

    elif post_data.get('archive') != None: # Don't do any validation 
        form.is_valid()
        cleaned_form = form.clean(full_clean=False)
        ...
        ...
        form.save()
        ...
```

The problem is, the form.clean() method is called when form.is_valid() is called so all the custom validation is still executed. I've also tried making `full_clean` default to `False` instead but then it won't validate properly when I want it to. If I remove the second `form.is_valid()` call, the cleaned_data doesn't get created and throws an error. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could serialize the "draft" data and save it in another table/model.
It's tricky to try to save your data that is not valid once it can be caught into some constraint from your data model. E.g. if you have a `not null` field and the user does not place value, how it could be saved in your database?

Comment: @JônatasCastro Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I completely understand that the model validation needs to happen exactly for the reason you stated. What I'm trying to do is skip over the validation I wrote when I overrode the form's clean() method. For example, one of the checks I make on a specific field is ensure the input is between 1 and 9. I want the cleaned data without my custom validation being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the init() and set a new field based on the `post_data`.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    archived = kwargs.pop('archived', None)
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['archived'] = forms.BooleanField(initial=archived, required=False)
```

and then actually add to your form

```
form = MyForm(request.post, archived=post_data.get('archived'))
```

In your custom clean() method, do a check for your self.fields.get('archived').

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.fields.get('archived']:
        # Do your validation
```

else it just skips over the custom validation.

Comment: That's an interesting approach though I do not have access to my the `post_data` in forms.py. Can you please elaborate on how I would set a new field in the init()? Thanks.

Comment: Just updated that post - let me know if that helps. @NoahSandler

Comment: I had to implement it slightly differently than how you have it here but your idea works exactly how I need. Thank you!